# How to get Pandas to xarray?

Tags: python

I am trying to convert a csv file from a pandas dataframe to an xarray.

here's what I have done so far.

```
import pandas as pd
atlantic = pd.read_csv('atlantic.csv', sep=',')
atlantic.to_xarray()
xr.open_dataset(atlantic)
```

But it does not work. Am I converting this correctly?

I basically want to be able to plot my data onto a 2d or 3d graph.

For the first two lines;

```
atlantic = pd.read_csv('atlantic.csv', sep=',')
    atlantic.to_xarray()
```

I get this which is what i want

```
 <xarray.Dataset>
    Dimensions:           (index: 49105)
    Coordinates:
      * index             (index) int64 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 ...
    Data variables:
        ID                (index) object 'AL011851' 'AL011851' 'AL011851' ...
        Name              (index) object '            UNNAMED' ...
        Date              (index) int64 18510625 18510625 18510625 18510625 ...
        Time              (index) int64 0 600 1200 1800 2100 0 600 1200 1800 0 ...
        Event             (index) object '  ' '  ' '  ' '  ' ' L' '  ' '  ' '  ' ...
        Status            (index) object ' HU' ' HU' ' HU' ' HU' ' HU' ' HU' ...
        Latitude          (index) object '28.0N' '28.0N' '28.0N' '28.1N' '28.2N' ...
        Longitude         (index) object '94.8W' '95.4W' '96.0W' '96.5W' '96.8W' ...
        Maximum Wind      (index) int64 80 80 80 80 80 70 60 60 50 50 40 40 40 ...
        Minimum Pressure  (index) int64 -999 -999 -999 -999 -999 -999 -999 -999 ...
        Low Wind NE       (index) int64 -999 -999 -999 -999 -999 -999 -999 -999 ...
        Low Wind SE       (index) int64 -999 -999 -999 -999 -999 -999 -999 -999 ...
        Low Wind SW       (index) int64 -999 -999 -999 -999 -999 -999 -999 -999 ...
        Low Wind NW       (index) int64 -999 -999 -999 -999 -999 -999 -999 -999 ...
        Moderate Wind NE  (index) int64 -999 -999 -999 -999 -999 -999 -999 -999 ...
        Moderate Wind SE  (index) int64 -999 -999 -999 -999 -999 -999 -999 -999 ...
        Moderate Wind SW  (index) int64 -999 -999 -999 -999 -999 -999 -999 -999 ...
        Moderate Wind NW  (index) int64 -999 -999 -999 -999 -999 -999 -999 -999 ...
        High Wind NE      (index) int64 -999 -999 -999 -999 -999 -999 -999 -999 ...
        High Wind SE      (index) int64 -999 -999 -999 -999 -999 -999 -999 -999 ...
        High Wind SW      (index) int64 -999 -999 -999 -999 -999 -999 -999 -999 ...
        High Wind NW      (index) int64 -999 -999 -999 -999 -999 -999 -999 -999 ...
```

but for line

```
xr.open_dataset(atlantic)
```

I get this;

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-34-1662445ac8e1> in <module>()
----> 1 xr.open_dataset(atlantic)

~/anaconda3_501/lib/python3.6/site-packages/xarray/backends/api.py in open_dataset(filename_or_obj, group, decode_cf, mask_and_scale, decode_times, autoclose, concat_characters, decode_coords, engine, chunks, lock, cache, drop_variables)
    322                              "default engine or engine='scipy'")
    323         # assume filename_or_obj is a file-like object
--> 324         store = backends.ScipyDataStore(filename_or_obj)
    325 
    326     return maybe_decode_store(store)

~/anaconda3_501/lib/python3.6/site-packages/xarray/backends/scipy_.py in __init__(self, filename_or_obj, mode, format, group, writer, mmap, autoclose, lock)
    144                                    filename=filename_or_obj,
    145                                    mode=mode, mmap=mmap, version=version)
--> 146         self._ds = opener()
    147         self._autoclose = autoclose
    148         self._isopen = True

~/anaconda3_501/lib/python3.6/site-packages/xarray/backends/scipy_.py in _open_scipy_netcdf(filename, mode, mmap, version)
     91     try:
     92         return scipy.io.netcdf_file(filename, mode=mode, mmap=mmap,
---> 93                                     version=version)
     94     except TypeError as e:  # netcdf3 message is obscure in this case
     95         errmsg = e.args[0]

~/anaconda3_501/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scipy/io/netcdf.py in __init__(self, filename, mode, mmap, version, maskandscale)
    235             self.filename = filename
    236             omode = 'r+' if mode == 'a' else mode
--> 237             self.fp = open(self.filename, '%sb' % omode)
    238             if mmap is None:
    239                 mmap = True

TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not DataFrame
```

Answer (score 1):

```
atlantic = atlantic.to_xarray()
```

Seems that it's unnecessary to call xr.open_dataset().

Answer (score 0):

`import pandas as pd
atlantic = pd.read_csv('atlantic.csv', sep=',')
data = atlantic.to_xarray()
xr.open_dataset(data)`

Comment: Yeah I know that I can use that instead, but I NEED it to be either an xarray or a NETCDF.

Comment: @weathergirl why doesn't your code work? did you get any error message? be more specific.

Comment: "TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not DataFrame"

Comment: @weathergirl at which line? edit your answer and include the full error message please.

Comment: @weathergirl you need to store `atlantic.to_xarray()` in a variable and then use `xr.open_dataset(variable_name)`